# Simple bruteforce algorithm in Swift

Tags: swift

So, I am learning Swift and as a little exercise I tried to implement a BruteForce algorithm. That algorithm is pretty simple however it is a bit slow too... Well, I am new to Swift, so maybe some optimisations are possible ?

Let's start with some useful prerequisites:

```
extension String {
    var digits:      String { return "0123456789" }
    var lowercase:   String { return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" }
    var uppercase:   String { return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" }
    var punctuation: String { return "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~" }
    var letters:     String { return lowercase + uppercase }
    var printable:   String { return digits + letters + punctuation }



    mutating func replace(at index: Int, with character: Character) {
        var stringArray = Array(self)
        stringArray[index] = character
        self = String(stringArray)
    }
}
```

Let's now implement the BruteForce algorithm

```
func indexOf(character: Character, _ array: [String]) -> Int {
    return array.firstIndex(of: String(character))!
}


func characterAt(index: Int, _ array: [String]) -> Character {
    return index < array.count ? Character(array[index])
                               : Character("")
}


func generateBruteForce(_ string: String, fromArray array: [String]) -> String {
    var str: String = string

    if str.count <= 0 {
        str.append(characterAt(index: 0, array))
    }
    else {
        str.replace(at: str.count - 1,
                    with: characterAt(index: (indexOf(character: str.last!, array) + 1) % array.count, array))

        if indexOf(character: str.last!, array) == 0 {
            str = String(generateBruteForce(String(str.dropLast()), fromArray: array)) + String(str.last!)
        }
    }

    return str
}
```

Now we can use it that way

```
import Foundation



let ALLOWED_CHARACTERS:   [String] = String().printable.map { String($0) }
let MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_SIZE:   Int   = 3



var password: String = ""

// Will strangely ends at 0000 instead of ~~~
while password.count <= MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_SIZE { // Increase MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_SIZE value for more
    password = generateBruteForce(password, fromArray: ALLOWED_CHARACTERS)
    // Your stuff here
    print(password)
    // Your stuff here
}
```

It will print

```
0
1
2
[...]
{
|
}
~
00
01
and so on...
```